# How to solve "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: sql-server, function

I am creating a Table value function in which I am using a `DATEENTER` type field `Datetime`, but when I execute my function it generates the following error message:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

The function I am using in SQL Server is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Function_TotalTravel](
    @YearTravel SMALLINT = 0,
    @MonthTravel SMALLINT = 0
)
RETURNS @Tabla TABLE (
    Travel VARCHAR(20),
    StatusTravel VARCHAR(20),
    DATEENTER DATETIME,
    IdStatusTravel INT
)
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO @Tabla (Travel,StatusTravel,DATEENTER,IdStatusTravel)
SELECT  V.Travel,
        V.DATEENTER,
        
            CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 'Travel Incomplete'
                    ELSE CASE 
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 2 THEN 'Transit'
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 3 THEN 'Closed'
                    WHEN V.StatusTravel = 4 THEN 'Cancel'
                    ELSE CAST(V.StatusTravel AS VARCHAR)
                    END END as 'StatusTravel',
            CASE    WHEN V.TravelIncomplete = 1 THEN 99
            ELSE    V.StatusTravel END IdStatusTravel
            
    FROM    TblTravel V WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   (DATEPART(YearTravel, V.DATEENTER) = @YearTravel OR @YearTravel = 0)
    AND     (DATEPART(MONTH, V.DATEENTER) = @MonthTravel OR @MonthTravel = 0)
    AND  ((V.StatusTravel NOT IN (0,1) AND V.TravelIncomplete = 0) OR V.TravelIncomplete = 1)

    RETURN
END
```

Try to perform a `CONVERT` on the select of the function as follows:

```
convert(varchar,DATEENTER),
```

But this one returns the same error message, any other solution that you can suggest.

Comment: Slight detour....here are two articles you should read. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length and  https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: Looks like your DATEENTER and StatusTravel select columns are the wrong way round. Your table has DATEENTER as the third column, but you're inserting it as the second.

Comment: @JoeJ  Nice catch!

Comment: If your entire function is truly what you posted you could eliminate the table variable completely. Just have the function return your select statement.